# Atmel printf formatting doesn't work, no formatting does work

Tags: avr, c, embedded, atmel, avr-gcc

We are running an Atmel AVR32 chip on our board, and recently discovered that **`printf` with format/conversion specifiers doesn't work. A regular `printf` does work.**

For instance,

```
printf("hello\n"); // works just fine
printf("number: %d\n", 12); // returns -1, nothing prints.
```

No format specifiers seem to have any effect, **printf just returns -1.**

We have tried linking in different versions of the `vfprintf` family of functions, e.g. adding `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm` to add floating point format capabilities (documented [here](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdio_1gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1.html)), but to no effect.

Note that we are NOT looking for floating point capabilities, **we are just trying to get ANY formatting** for a regular decimal (int, uint_8, etc.).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know a lot about AVR, but I know printf is kind of bulky, and I remember there is a tinyprintf that I once saw recommended for embedded systems: https://github.com/cjlano/tinyprintf

Comment: Perhaps it's incomplete?  Maybe try just the %d and number by itself?

Comment: It's not obvious what the issue is immediately, but how about a test to get some more info?  Run these through sprintf to see if the formatting is what is failing.  It could be something to do with the output stream.

Comment: Does `%i` work as expected?

Comment: Cross posting within the SE network is not permitted, you may ask this on EESE or SO, **but not both**.  You must delete either this or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651671/atmel-printf-formatting-doesnt-work-no-formatting-does-work  (FWIW, I maintain that the separation of sites is broken design - all the tech sites should be unified, with potentially overlapping specialities handled by tags and tag filters)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok I've deleted the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a character buffer, formatting it, and then printing it?

```
   char buffer [50];
   int A = 12;
   i = sprintf (buffer, "A: %d \n", A);

   printf(buffer);
```

Also, try initializing the variable first, then include it inside the printf.

```
   int A = 12; 
   printf("number: %d \n", A);
```

Comment: I second using sprintf first into a char buffer, you can't go wrong with that.

Comment: If the formatting code has been trimmed to make printf fit, (which it almost certainly has) then it'll be missing for sprintf too